# PREG function family in PHP

Tags: php, regex, templates

I am building an template engine and I am thinking to use preg_split(); but instead of using '{' and '}' I am thinking to use '[@' and '@]' but I would like to implement functionality like in smarty. { tag_to_replace | escape_html } and I would like to be able to get everything after the | delimiter. What should be the best way to implement that functionality.

Thank you all in advance!
Please don't give me suggestions to use SMARTY or any other template engine. I am building my own PHP Framework (for learning purposes) and would like to implement one. Thank you very much.

Cheers!

Comment: Template engines shouldn't use regexes as their primary parsing component. How would you nest tags?

Comment: Stack Overflow works best if you have one *specific* question instead of: this is what I want, now go make it for me and tell how everythings works while you are at it.

Comment: I see you have edited your question. However in it's edited form is is still too broad to give you a good answer.

Comment: One hint: If you want to learn, you can also take a look into existing engines how they do it. Probably smarty not the best one to look into, if you like to start with something smaller, why not the C version ctags or mustache?

Comment: You understood my point right? If you @PeeHaa could suggest and edit I will be more than happy.

Comment: If I think I can fix it I would be more than happy to do so, however I don't know what the specific question is you have.

Comment: In very short I wanted to ask how to implement smary-like functionality to be able to set parameters within my tags: '[@' and '@]'hope this helps

Comment: First you lex into tokens, then you parse the tokens with your parser. You can build these things with Twig, it's an engine, too. Take a look there-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very good short "cheat sheet" and testing tool for regular expressions, play with it. But i agree - template engine should be much simpler.

http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm